# Помогите разобраться с python request session

Tags: python, requests

Помогите разобраться в принципе работы сессий

Допустим, я создал функцию auth с переменной сессии

```py
s = requests.Session()
```

Затем, в конце функции создал переменную для пост запроса

```py
r = s.post("site.ru", data=data_, cookies=cookies_)
return r.text
```

Сессия создана в функции авторизации на сайте.
Эта функция создает сессию, решает каптчу, делает пост запрос с заголовками.

На следующем этапе мне нужно обращаться к полученным из функции данным.

И вот здесь возникает вопрос:
Если я обращаюсь в таком виде get_page_data(auth()) я буду инициировать выполнение всех шагов функции auth() или просто получу пресловутый r.text

Главный вопрос - как правильно обращаться из других функций, чтобы сессия оставалась активной?
Спасибо

Comment: можно передавать `Session` объект в функции в качестве параметра